# How to initialize `static` member polymorphically

Tags: c++, polymorphism, static-members

Say I have base class `Validator`.

```
class Validator
{
public:
  void validate(const string& str)
  {
    if( k_valid_keys.find(str) == k_valid_keys.end() ) 
      throw exception();
  }
private:
  const static std::set<string> k_valid_keys;
};
```

Now assume I need to extend class `Validator`. Each derived class will have its own set of valid keys.
**My goal is:**

1. keep `k_valid_keys` a member of `Validator`. No need to add it to each derived classes especially when there are more than a few types of those.
2. keep `k_valid_keys` `static`. Assume I have multiple instances of `Validator` (and its derived classed) and initialization of `k_valid_keys` is expensive.

How can I initialize `static` member polymorphically? well, I know that it can't be done (please correct if I'm wrong).

So Assuming it can't be done, any idea of a better design for this problem?

Comment: You say "Each derived class will have its own set of valid keys", so will every derived class have its own static set of valid keys?

Comment: this is what I'm trying to avoid. why add `static` to each derived class if I can magically initialize it virtually.

Comment: You could have an inherited virtual function with a static variable inside of it.

Comment: Yet again, this doesn't help me avoid having `k_valid_keys` in each derived class.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a member variable, and you'll inherit the parent class' validation if you don't override it.

Comment: perhaps we are not on the same page. I'd appreciate if you could post an answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `k_valid_keys` is `static` declared at `Validator`, all the derived classes from `Validator` will share the same instance of `k_valid_keys`. That's it, you will not be able to have more than one instance of a subclass of `Validator` at the same time in your program, else your different instances of subclases of `Validator` will add elements to the same structure.

That's is, a static member variable on a class is just a global variable of your entire program.

If you have two or more subclases of `Validator` but you guarantee that you are going to have only just one instance, you just initialize `k_valid_keys` on the subclass constructor.

Comment: You are right. thanks for clarifying this. So I assume that what I'm asking for is not feasible?

Comment: @idanshmu IMHO Too many constraints, I guess. Why do you need k_valid_keys static? Performance?

Comment: because it is static in nature. it shouldn't be bound to an instance since it is constant per `Validator` class. I failed to understand that my constrains makes not sense.

Comment: @idanshmu What about moving the static k_valid_keys field to each subclass?

Comment: That's what I have to do. I was trying to avoid that because I didn't understand that I can't have multiple definitions for `static` member ( as you correctly stated ). I was trying to keep subclass as clean as possible but it can't be done that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following: instead of one set of the keys as static member, use a map mapping std::type_index to set of keys (or, if you cannot use C++11, std::type_info*). In each of your derived classes have a virtual function which returns the set of valid_keys for a class, and the `validate` function in the base class should get with `typeid` the `type_info` of the actual object, check if it already has the keys in the map - if not, the virtual function return the set is called, and the entry is added to the map.

Comment: this doesn't help me avoid having `k_valid_keys` in each derived class.

Comment: Yes it does. The map I am proposing is the static member of the base class. The only thing to be added in the derived classes is a virtual function returning the keys, and each such function will be called only once.

Comment: OK. now I see where you're going with this. seems about right.

Comment: There is a [standard facility](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) for this, since `type_info*` isn't guaranteed to do the right thing.

Comment: Although `type_index` could be used here, I don't see the necessity for `rtti` at all.

Comment: What do you propose without RTTI?

Answer (score 0):

Pass a reference to `k_valid_keys` in the constructor of your `Validator` classes and initialize a member reference. You'll skip construction for multiple `Validator` classes but you'll have to manage its lifetime.

You can then have one per inherited type if you want or not as well.

Using a register of `k_valid_keys` that is accessed by type or key could also work. Of course you would need to pass a reference to this register to your `Validator` classes.